# Telling almost identical windows apart in Windows

Tags: windows

I often have several open windows that are almost identical (like reports from running multiple performance checks on different stages of the same application).

Is there a way to make individual window instances easily identifiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to investigate using this piece of software, [Window Title Changer](https://www.murgee.com/window-title-changer/). According to the description of the software, it looks like it can provide custom titles for multiple windows, even if the windows are minimized. Should work for Windows XP through 10.  It will give you a list of open windows which you can give custom titles.